Use custom font on KomaScript Report class
I am fairly new to LaTeX, and I developed a template that I use for all my reports and course notes, etc.
The template uses the KomaScript Report class, and I tried different ways to change the Font for the document but the part that I am interested in changing its font, doesn't change.
TL;DR: I want to use a custom font for the Chapter title, Section, Subsections and other part of the document using the "scrreprt" class. How can I accomplish this?
Thanks to anyone that will answer.
here is the link to the GitHub page of the template.
https://github.com/not-icosahedron/LaTeX-Notes-Template
feel free to use either GitHub to propose a solution, or on here.

Please make sure that your questions is self-sustained to ensure that your question remains useful to future users even if your link stops working.

\setkomafont{disposition}{\yourFontHere}

You question is not really clear. Do you want to change the default sans-serif font used by KOMA-Script to another font? In this case, you should just load a suitable font package or use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and fontspec + \setsansfont. Or do you want to replace all sans-serif default by roman? In this case you should see option sfdefaults in the user manual. Or do you want to change the fonts of all sectioning levels at once. See Skillmon's comment. Or do you want to change the fonts of individual sectioning levels. See \setkomafont in the user manual.

BTW: I cannot recommend the template. It uses deprecated packages like a4wide and not recommended package combinations that even result in warning messages. And it even uses packages like emptypage that are not needed, because KOMA-Script classes provide similar features out of the box.

Changing the font of the headings in KOMAscript document classes can be done just as Sillmon in his comment says. But from your main.tex in github I see that you haven't just gotten your head around the font selection in the pdfLaTeX engine (package fontenc) and the LuaLaTeX enging (package fontspec). If you chose LuaLaTeX, instead of ulem look for lua-ul and luacolor. Post a minimal working example with any question!

@cabohah No, this isn't what our OP here is asking. He is just doing the second step before the first one: trying to change the headings before deciding about LuaTeX or PDFTeX and the main font.

@KeksDose You are reading a lot from a faulty file (see the several issues reported). Whether you're right or not ... I don't know.

As an example how to do it using LuaLaTeX:
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto}[BoldFont=Roboto Bold,
ItalicFont=RobotoItalic,
BoldItalicFont=Roboto Bold Italic]
\setsansfont{Roboto}[BoldFont=Roboto Bold,
ItalicFont=Roboto Italic,
BoldItalicFont=Roboto Bold Italic]

\newfontfamily{\myheadings}{Alegreya Regular}[BoldFont=Alegreya Bold,
ItalicFont=Alegreya Italic,BoldItalicFont=Alegreya Bold Italic]

\setkomafont{disposition}{\myheadings}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{babel}

\title{Long title in Alegreya font}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:

You get the manual for KOMAscript usually with texdoc scrguide-enon the command line. Read fontspec (texdoc fontspec) and have a look into the documentation of luaotfload-tool and luaotfload itself.

Instead of setting the same font as main font and as sans font and then adding a third font as new family, IMHO it would make more sense to use a different sans font. In this case you would also not need the \setkomafont. But this is also only a guess, because it is really not clear, what the OP wants. See my comment(s) to the question.
